# "Please join me, my family and [my] crew." Can the second "my" be left out?

Tags: grammar, phrases, american-english, coordinating-conjunctions, possessive-pronouns

Is it proper to say:

> Please join me, my family and crew in celebrating my Bat Mitzvah?

Or should there be a 'my' before crew?

Comment: _Crew_ is a fairly unusual word to use for an invitation to a religious ceremony. It implies the crew members have some unified structure, and you're in command of them; it doesn't just indicate that you're a member of the group. There's no need to repeat _my_ before _crew_, but it should have a comma after _family_, and think hard about the last word. _Mob_? _Friends_? Whatever.

Comment: @JohnLawler There is surely a serious part to many religious ceremonies, but I think there is some leeway for levity. Man, best party _ever_ for 13 year olds!

Comment: @Mitch: True enough about levity. And Judaism has some of the best jokes of any religion, also true. And it's **her** Bat Mitzvah, truest of all. Whatever; it's just that _crew_ has an interpretation, and the comma has an intonation. Nu, she's asking for information, she gets information. מזל טוב

Answer (score 3):

The "Oxford comma is irrelevant to this question.

Saying "my family and crew" implies that the crew is part of the family, not necessarily your crew.  Saying "my family and my crew" implies that both the family and crew "belong" to you, which is probably what you are looking for.

In addition, unless you are a ship's captain, you may want to use an alternative collection reference rather than "crew", such as "friends", "gang", or "colleagues".

Answer (score 0):

***my family and crew***

it's out there:

> **National Geographic** - Volume 188 - Page 88 1995
>
> French long-liners. French Navy gunboats showed up. They fired on my
>   boat with rubber bullets," he said, his eyes red with anger. "If these
>   foreign boats are going to destroy our way of life, to take away the
>   livelihood of **my family and crew,**

And no, the Oxford comma would be required only if this were:

*Please join me, **my family, and the crew** in celebrating my Bat Mitzvah?"

when the "crew" would be separated from "family."

The way you have it "my family and crew," "family" and "crew" are combined in a single unit for some. For others, it'd be just an elision of another "my," to avoid repetition.

If you used "crew" instead of "gang" I think you're fine with it as it is if you really want to make this light and casual.

> Riccardo Tisci Interview - Givenchy, Joan Smalls, Lara ...
>
> Apr 3, 2015 - I'm building relationships for years and years. I have
>   **my family and gang**, which we carry on season after season. Since you
>   approach things from the perspective of building long-term
>   relationships, what do you look for when

But this **my family and gang** is relatively rare.